# result of matching analysis in confounding case

Tags: matching, confounding

currently I'm studying Observation Analysis in my college. 
One of the part study explain about matching analysis in confounding case.

In here, they told me that when we doing matched analysis, somehow we need to selected randomly our data which mean the result itself for each random data would be different. But the purpose to doing this actually to get better result. So, it's that true? Or Am i missing something here? Coz when we present our result to our lecturer, my friend and I get different result so the result itself was not get better but more confusing.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few ways randomness can creep into a matching algorithm. One is when you are doing 1:1 matching and two control units are the same distance from a treated unit. Some matching algorithms will randomly select one of the control units to be matched. It doesn't matter which one you choose in terms of bias, but there may be some consequences for precision.

Another way is when you are doing caliper matching and you randomly select a control unit from within the caliper of the treated unit. Here it would be preferable not to randomly select but rather to use an optimal selection. Nearest neighbor would work well here.

The only time I've seen a random component been recommended in matching is when doing nearest neighbor matching. Some authors recommend randomizing the order of the treated units so that it's not the case that treated units with the lowest/high propensity scores get matched first. This makes it so the best matches aren't used up at one side of the propensity score distribution or the other, but rather are distributed across the sample. This type of randomization does improve estimates but can also yield varying results across analyses. My preference would be to randomize a few times, perhaps using different seeds, and select the one matched set that has the best balance and the smallest within-pair distances.